# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead: array=5.5

Tags: python, machine-learning, python-3.7

Why am I getting the error below?

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead: array=5.5.
>   Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a
>   single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("decision-tree-regression-dataset.csv",sep = ";",header = None)
x = df.iloc[:,0].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df.iloc[:,1].values.reshape(-1,1)

# decision tree regression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
tree_reg = DecisionTreeRegressor()   # random sate = 0
tree_reg.fit(x,y)
tree_reg.predict(5.5)
x_ = np.arange(min(x),max(x),0.01).reshape(-1,1)
y_head = tree_reg.predict(x_)

# visualize
plt.scatter(x,y,color="red")
plt.plot(x_,y_head,color = "green")
plt.xlabel("tribun level")
plt.ylabel("ucret")
plt.show()
```

Comment: What line throws the error? `tree_reg.predict(5.5)`? What is the output of `x.shape`?

Comment: Could you plase paste the whole error trackback? It is a lot easier to find the problem that way.

Comment: @sentence What line throws the error? -idk- tree_reg.predict(5.5)? -so:)- What is the output of x.shape? -where i need to write x.shape?-

Comment: @funie200 comment box says for whole error trackback 'too long characters' so cant add sorry

Answer (score 0):

try to use this to predict :

```
  tree_reg.predict([[5.5]])
```

note to use [[]] as 2d array  which like (sample_num, feature_num)

Comment: it worked tnx so much. i m learning python from udemy. and the courses are from 2017 etc. i think all errors i take bec. of update problem. i mean their versions are old